# Acumatica - WebAPI return format

Tags: acumatica

Acumatica Objects in webAPI has return format Like

```
Property:{
value: value of property
}
```

While general class property structure is

```
Property:Value of Property
```

For integration purpose this is the major task to convert the data from Format one to second Format, Is there any way define on Acumatica by which the data can be extracted directly in second format.

Note - I know Acumatica defines the class for each property and that class is having the Value as and property in to it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly it is not possible thru the contract based REST API, you could return custom data structures in a webhook handler. The reason is because in newer endpoint versions if there is an error you get this as well:

```
Property:{
   value: value of property
   error: error message here
}
```